# Determine Is the keyboard folded back or not on Surface pro

Tags: c#, .net, surface

I have a Win32 application. It runs on Surface Pro with Windows 8.1. Surface has a type cover (http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/type-cover). This cover has position "Folded back" in which noone key is not print on screen

> To type text while the Cover is folded back, tap in a text field or area where you can type and the on-screen keyboard appears.

Is it possible to get from code (.net C#) "Is the keyboard folded back or not"?

Thank in advance!